# Group by date and take the last one

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my table :

[image: Database]

What I'm trying to do, is to take the last disponibility of a user, by caserne. Example, I should have this result :

```
id    id_user    id_caserne    id_dispo    created_at
31    21         12            1           2019-10-24 01:21:46
33    21         13            1           2019-10-23 20:17:21
```

I've tried this sql, but it does not seems to work all the times :

```
SELECT * FROM 
    ( SELECT id, id_dispo, id_user, id_caserne, MAX(created_at) 
    FROM disponibilites GROUP BY id_user, id_caserne, id_dispo 
    ORDER BY created_at desc ) AS sub 
GROUP BY id_user, id_caserne
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would simply use filtering in the `where` clause using a correlated subquery:

```
select d.*
from disponibilites d
where d.created_at = (select max(d2.created_at)
                      from disponibilites d2
                      where d2.id_user = d.id_user
                     );
```

EDIT:

Based on your comments:

```
select d.*
from disponibilites d
where d.created_at = (select max(d2.created_at)
                      from disponibilites d2
                      where d2.id_user = d.id_user and
                            d2.id_caserne = d.id_caserne
                      where date(d2.created_at) = date(d.created_at)
                     );
```

Comment: I need to get all records for a user, grouped by id_caserne and by created_at. So i need the last one for 2019-10-23 and the last one for 2019-10-24 (for example, not in the database actually)

Comment: @CodeVeteran . . . You can just extend the conditions in the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a correlated subquery, as demonstrated by Gordon Linoff, or a window function if your RDBMS supports it:

```
select * from (
    select 
        t.*,
        rank() over(partition by id_caserne, id_user order by created_at desc) rn
    from disponibilites t
) x
where rn = 1
```

Another option is to use a correlated subquery without aggregation, only with a sort and limit:

```
select *
from mytable t
where created_at = (
    select created_at
    from mytable t1
    where t1.id_user = t.id_user and t1.id_caserne = t.id_caserne
    order by created_at desc
    limit 1
)
```

With an index on `(id_user, id_caserne, created_at)`, this should be a very efficient option.

Comment: No, it doesn't support it. Sorry :/

Comment: @CodeVeteran: which RDBMS / version are you actually using? You can also add the relevant tag to your question.

Comment: My RDBMS is mysql

Comment: OK. Window functions are available from MySQL 8.0. I also added another option to my answer which works in earlier versions of MySQL and avoids using aggregation (`group by`).

Answer (score 0):

you can `join` your `max(created_date)` to your original table

```
select t1.* from disponibilites t1
inner join
    (select max(created_at), id_caserne, id 
    from disponibilites 
    group by id_caserne, id) t2
on t2.id = t1.id
```